# How can I make the OVH server send an email?

Tags: php, symfony, email, verification, ovh

This is the code:

```
$transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport( "".$entity->getHost(), $entity->getPort(), 'ssl');

$transport->setUsername("".$entity->getUsername())->setPassword("".$entity->getPassword());

$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

$message = new Swift_Message('Test Edit');
$message
    ->setFrom([$entity->getUsername() => 'nani'])
    ->setTo(['tech@email.com' => 'Recipient'])
    ->setSubject('Test Edit')
    ->setBody('Test Message', 'text/html');

$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

I want OVH server send the email, but this set up is sending the email with my ip server instead of OVH ip.

Comment: What does this return `$entity->getHost()`?

Comment: $entity->getHost() returns this:
SSL0.OVH.NET

Comment: That means it is sending with ovh. Not sure what you mean by *sending with my ip*?

Comment: my ip(the platform im using and where the code is) is shown on the headers of the email even when the email is sended via ovh @Bossman